# How to dynamically add data source in RDLC report with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, report

I have defined one report "Report1.rdlc" with one database (Database2)

[image]

That database has one datatable defines, with no columns or rows.

I want to add one datable to my report dynamically, because i will not know hoy many columns or rows will have my table. Is that possible?

I have tried add in my class Page_Load  the datable to my report viewer:

[image]

Bur the report doesn't show anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Keix  Is that possible? I am sure you can create the the structure of the data table but you need to add columns then add the data The issue I see is we do not know what type of database you are using ? SQLite Next issue is each table needs to accommodate X number of columns SO how do you plan to add additional columns to the table HINT this is a lot of work SO let us know what DB you plan to use and figure out how to add additional columns

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if is that possible. The thing is if i can update dynamically the dataset of the report .rdlc or change in runtime the dataset.

Comment: Can you grab the data ? Then put it in your own SQLite DB     I am still asking what id the DB ? I assume you did not create the DB if so then you need to be able to have access to make reports